# modificar y eliminar registro desde gridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

estoy haciendo un CRUD con vb.net en una aplicacion web, solo que trato de colocar unlink en un Gridview para actualizar y eliminar pero no se como hacerlo, el gridview ya lo lleno de datos de la siguiente manera:

mi funcion donde hago la consulta y devuelvo los resultados

```
    Public Function consultar() As DataTable
    Dim cn = "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=curso;User Id=sa;Password=****"

    Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)
    conexion.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = conexion
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT*FROM TELEFONO"

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    Return dt
End Function
```

mi codebehind

```
Public Class Consultar
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim muestraDatos As New Operaciones

    GridView1.DataSource = muestraDatos.consultar()
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub
```

End Class

mi gridview en la pagina aspx

```html
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Consultar.aspx.vb" Inherits="Entrevista.Consultar" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
    <div>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que yo personalmente haria es crear metodos para actualizar o borrar registros, luego de eso por ultimo llamaria a consultar() despues de realizar alguna de las dos operaciones para que el datagridview refresque. Por ejemplo:

```
Public sub ActualizarRegistro(ByVal columna as String, ByVal A as String, ByVal B as String)
Dim cn = "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=curso;User Id=sa;Password=****"

 Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)
 conexion.Open()

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = conexion
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TELEFONO SET " & columna & "=@A WHERE " & columna & "=@B"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(A,"@A")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(B,"@B")
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conexion.Close()
cmd.Dispose()
conexion.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Esto que vez aqui (las cadenas seguidas con @), por si no lo conocias, se llaman **consultas parameterizadas**. Son mas rapidas y seguras (te protegen del famoso **SQL INJECTION**), asi que siempre acostumbra a escribirlas. (Los unicos valores que no se pueden pasar como parametro son las columnas, por eso no hay de otra que concatenarlas)

Como primer parametro le pasas la columna de la tabla, el valor A es el dato nuevo que vas a ingresar y el dato B es el existente. Necesitaras capturar el dato viejo al momento de hacer clic en alguna celda del datagridview (A la vez que tambien tendrias que capturar el nombre de la columna para el parametro "columna") esto lo podrias lograr con los eventos del datagridview (el CellClic o CellContentClic como bien desees) y podrias capturarlos asi:

```
Dim datoViejo As String = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
Dim nombreColumna As String = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.HeaderCell.Value
```

Bien, con otro evento del datagridview podrias ejecutar el metodo que acabe de escribir (el de actualizar) y seguido llamo la funcion que creaste para consultar (consultar()) asi se hace un "refresh" del datagridview... esto lo haria con el evento CellLeave. Basicamente el proceso seria asi:

**Das clic a la celda que deseas modificar, en este momento que das clic la pagina captura el nombre de la columna y el dato que contiene la celda.**

**Le has dado clic a la celda, tienes el foco puesto en ella, es momento de escribir el dato nuevo a reemplazar.**

**Al dar clic en otro lugar, el foco en la celda se pierde y empezara inmediatamente la ejecucion del metodo escrito mas arriba.**

CONSEJOS: Viendo que estas creando la conexion en una funcion y no es un atributo de clase que puedas reutilizar en diferentes funciones o metodos, es recomendable que cuando termines de utilizarlo uses el metodo **Dispose()** para liberar recursos en la pagina. Esto tambien cuenta con **SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter**, incluso los mismos **DataTables** al momento de terminar de usarlo es recomendable eliminarlo... siempre cuando termines de usar algo, eliminalo.

Ya por ultimo, tienes que abrir la conexion para trabajar verdad? asi mismo cuando termines de hacer algo con la base de datos, cierra la conexion.

Tu funcion que has posteado yo lo escribiria de la siguiente manera:

```
Public Function consultar() As DataTable
Dim cn = "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=curso;User Id=sa;Password=****"

Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)
conexion.Open()

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = conexion
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT*FROM TELEFONO"

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
da.SelectCommand = cmd
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)

'Liberacion de recursos'
da.Dispose()
cmd.Dispose()
cn.Close()
cn.Dispose()

Return dt
End Function
```

Ya por ultimo no creo que necesites una sentencia delete... si lo necesitaras igual, la mecanica de la consulta no cambiaria en nada, lo unico que cambiaria es el valor de CommandText (que escribirias aqui la clausula DELETE). Espero que esta respuesta te haya iluminado en lo que deseas.

Si te ha servido esta respuesta, por favor no dudes en marcarla :)

Saludos